# WCF sending large (>90Mb) XML files from client to third party via WCF service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I want to send a large XML file in its entirety from source to a third party machine via a WCF service in C#.  The files can be as large as 90Mbs

Trying to serialize the XML to a string takes far too long and will use up all the memory.  I've seen a lot of answers that tell me to try picking out the relevant information from the XML file that I want to send, but I need to be able to send the full file and allow the third party to process the files.

How would be best to approach this?

Comment: This link might help for transferring large files http://garfoot.com/blog/2008/06/transferring-large-files-using-wcf/

Answer (score 2):

This may be of some help.

[Custom WCF Streaming](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2012/09/06/custom-wcf-streaming.aspx)

Comment: As it stands, this is litte more than a link-only answer. If the link goes down, your answer will be hard to understand for future visitors. See [FAQ: Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be very applicable:
[Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Basically it is possible to stream binary data in a WCF payload. This can come from a stream - so you can even avoid loading all the data in memory (if you can, i.e. if they come from a file).

Comment: As it stands, this is litte more than a link-only answer. If the link goes down, your answer will be hard to understand for future visitors. See [FAQ: Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Use basichttpbinding with streaming and MTOM encoding.

[Info about the topic](http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/mtom-vs-streaming-vs-compression-%E2%80%93-large-attachments-over-wcf/)

Comment: No comment on the downvote?

Comment: As it stands, this is litte more than a link-only answer. If the link goes down, your answer will be hard to understand for future visitors. See [FAQ: Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: So basichttpbinding with streaming and MTOM encoding, is not enough? What does the OP want that we develop his application? If the OP would show some effort of what he has done we might be more willing to actually write code on where it goes wrong. Basically what is asked is please write my code because I don't know how to google it.

Comment: A poor question is not a reason to give a poor answer, better just leave a comment on the question then. I've voted to close the question as "too broad".